# Filtering coordinates tuples (F#)

Tags: .net, arrays, f#, type-conversion, tuples

I have an array `A` of coordinates (as tuples) like this:

```
let A = [|(1,5);(3,3);(4,5);(6,3);(5,1);(2,2)|]
```

I want to delete all the tuples `(a,b)` that have an "opposite" `(b,a)` element in the same array. I've been able to remove the coordinates `(1,5)` and `(5,1)`, but I'm also deleting `(2,2)` and `(3,3)`, but I don't know how to avoid that.

Comment: Can you make that part about (2,2), (3,3) clearer? I understand there's some kind of rule about which elements you want to filter out other then them being (1,5) and (5,1).

Comment: I said it because in the case of (1,5) and (5,1) the rule is like "for an (a,b) tuple, if there is a (b,a) tuple, delete them." In case of (2,2) and (3,3) the rule also applies so they should be deleted too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure something like this should be faster.

```
let hashTuple = function
    | f, s when f > s -> (s, f)
    | f, s -> (f, s)


let filter (a: seq<int*int>) =
    a
    |> Seq.filter (fun (f, s) -> f <> s)
    |> Seq.countBy hashTuple
    |> Seq.filter (fun g -> snd g = 1)
    |> Seq.map fst
```

Comment: It's faster, but not faster enought. Thanks anyway!

Comment: How fast do you need it? You should be able to parallel it. See here.
http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq/

Comment: I need to use this for 10k tuples (aprox) and do all this operationes in less than 1 sec. Can't install collections.

Comment: I ran the code above against 100k tuples and it works fine. 10k in less than a second shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind quadratic complexity:

```
let B = A |> Array.filter (fun (a,b) -> 
    not (A |> Array.exists (fun (a',b') -> a=b' && b=a')))
```

Comment: Yep, this is what i need. I hope it supports a big amount of data. Thanks

Comment: Well, it's too slow. Is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: You can try to use a Set:

let S = A |> Set.ofArray;

let B = S |> Set.filter (fun (a,b) -> not (S |> Set.exists (fun (a',b') -> a=b' && b=a')))

Comment: It's the same, Jindřich?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
let B = A.[1..A.Length-2]
```

?

Comment: How does it works and why still there (2,2) and (3,3) tuples?

Comment: It declares B as a sub-array of A, but it ignores the first and the last elements.

Comment: That0s not what i'm looking for. I create A just like an example. I need to filter the "(a,b)/(b,a)" tuples.